# How to Read Review Status,Comments,Modified By Columns of FileCollection Using Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

How to read all columns of a File using Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.dll.

Actually my documents resides into sub folders so i am using ExecuteQuery() and once i am reaching to the specified documents folder then loading all the files into filecollection of that folder in to Context and then trying to read the columns of the webpage along with the excel file name.

[image]

In the above Image you can find the Yellow highligted columns.I want to read those columns from c#.
Below is the code which i had written:-

```
            string siteUrl = @"http://localhost";
        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
        clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("*****", "*****", "*****");
        Web site = clientContext.Web;
        FolderCollection SearchFolder = site.Folders;
        clientContext.Load(SearchFolder);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        //Iterating each folder inside the website
        foreach (Folder searchFolder in SearchFolder)
            {
            if (searchFolder.Name == "Random Scan Tracking")
                {
                //Displays and Logs Message
                _loggerDetails.LogMessage = "Search Folder : " + searchFolder.Name;
                _writeLog.LogDetails(_loggerDetails.LogLevel_Info, _loggerDetails.LogMessage);

                Console.WriteLine("Search Folder : " + searchFolder.Name);
                FolderCollection RegionFolder=searchFolder.Folders;
                clientContext.Load(RegionFolder);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                //Iterating each Region Folder inside the Random Scan Folder
                foreach (Folder regionFolder in RegionFolder)
                    {
                    Console.WriteLine("Region Folder : " + regionFolder.Name);
                    //Displays and Logs Message
                    _loggerDetails.LogMessage = "Region Folder : " + regionFolder.Name;
                    _writeLog.LogDetails(_loggerDetails.LogLevel_Info, _loggerDetails.LogMessage);

                    FolderCollection StateFOlder=regionFolder.Folders;
                    clientContext.Load(StateFOlder);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    //Iterating each State Folder inside the Region Folder
                    foreach (Folder stateFolder in StateFOlder)
                        {
                        Console.WriteLine("State Folder : " + stateFolder.Name);
                        //Displays and Logs Message
                        _loggerDetails.LogMessage = "State Folder : " + stateFolder.Name;
                        _writeLog.LogDetails(_loggerDetails.LogLevel_Info, _loggerDetails.LogMessage);

                        FolderCollection CountyFolder=stateFolder.Folders;
                        clientContext.Load(CountyFolder);
                        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                        //Iterating each County Folder inside the State Folder
                        foreach (Folder countyFolder in CountyFolder)
                            {
                            Console.WriteLine("County Folder : " + countyFolder.Name);
                            //Displays and Logs Message
                            _loggerDetails.LogMessage = "County Folder : " + countyFolder.Name;
                            _writeLog.LogDetails(_loggerDetails.LogLevel_Info, _loggerDetails.LogMessage);

                            FolderCollection MonthFolder=countyFolder.Folders;
                            clientContext.Load(MonthFolder);
                            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                            //Iterating each Month Folder inside the County Folder
                            foreach (Folder monthFolder in MonthFolder)
                                {
                                Console.WriteLine("Month Folder : " + monthFolder.Name);
                                //Displays and Logs Message
                                _loggerDetails.LogMessage = "Month Folder : " + monthFolder.Name;
                                _writeLog.LogDetails(_loggerDetails.LogLevel_Info, _loggerDetails.LogMessage);

                                FileCollection flc=monthFolder.Files;
                                clientContext.Load(flc);
                                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                                foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file in flc)
                                    {
                                    Console.WriteLine("File Name : " + file.Name);
                                    Console.WriteLine("File Check out By Name : " + file.CheckedOutByUser.ToString());
                                    Console.WriteLine("FileCheck in Comment : " + file.CheckInComment.ToString());
                                    Console.WriteLine("Modified ByComment : " + file.ModifiedBy.ToString());
                                    Console.WriteLine("Modified Date : " + file.TimeLastModified.ToString());
                                    Console.WriteLine("Created Date : " + file.TimeCreated.ToString());
                                    //Displays and Logs Message
                                    _loggerDetails.LogMessage = "File Name : " + file.Name;
                                    _writeLog.LogDetails(_loggerDetails.LogLevel_Info, _loggerDetails.LogMessage);
                                    //Displays and Logs Message
                                    _loggerDetails.LogMessage = "File Check out By Name : " + file.CheckedOutByUser.ToString();
                                    _writeLog.LogDetails(_loggerDetails.LogLevel_Info, _loggerDetails.LogMessage);
                                    //Displays and Logs Message
                                    _loggerDetails.LogMessage = "FileCheck in Comment : " + file.CheckInComment.ToString();
                                    _writeLog.LogDetails(_loggerDetails.LogLevel_Info, _loggerDetails.LogMessage);
                                    //Displays and Logs Message
                                    _loggerDetails.LogMessage = "Modified ByComment : " + file.ModifiedBy.ToString();
                                    _writeLog.LogDetails(_loggerDetails.LogLevel_Info, _loggerDetails.LogMessage);
                                    //Displays and Logs Message
                                    _loggerDetails.LogMessage = "Modified Date : " + file.TimeLastModified.ToString();
                                    _writeLog.LogDetails(_loggerDetails.LogLevel_Info, _loggerDetails.LogMessage);
                                    //Displays and Logs Message
                                    _loggerDetails.LogMessage = "Created Date : " + file.TimeCreated.ToString();
                                    _writeLog.LogDetails(_loggerDetails.LogLevel_Info, _loggerDetails.LogMessage);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

I am able to read the filename, modified by of each file but i want to read the Modified Date, Review Status, Comments and Checked out to columns also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your last foreach statement :

Add following code:

```
ListItem item = file.ListItemAllFields;
clientContext.Load(item);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
string strModified = item["Modified"].ToString();
strint comments = item["Comments"].ToString();
```

Get other fields like this.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Already tried this but not able to read Modified,Modified By,Review Status,Comments Columns. Updated my code also in the question. I am Able to get details of the excel which is there but not able to get other details which are displaying there on the website as highlighted in the image too.

Comment: Actually these documents resides into sub folders so i am using ExecuteQuery() and once i am reaching to the specified documents folder then loading all the filecollection of that folder in to Context and then trying to read the columns of the webpage along with the excel file name.

Comment: Thanks AAnchal for the answer but Still Not able to read item["Modified By"],item["Review Status"] and item["Checked Out To"] columns.Getting exception as  'item["Checked Out To"]' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException'

Comment: Use that columns internal names while referencing them